# Set umask for an individual salt state

Tags: salt

Is there a way to set the umask for the pip state module or is there a more generic way to set the umask before specific state modules are run? In ansible the pip module takes a umask parameter. I do not see an equivalent option in the salt pip state module. We run salt-call with a umask of 007 but we need to install certain python packages with more open permissions; is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edit update April 3rd 2023:

As of salt 3006 (https://salt.tips/whats-new-in-salt-sulfur/#umask) umask is now a global state argument and can be specified on any state.

### Original work around for pre 3006

I ended up working around this by creating a custom state module that wraps any state that I want to set the umask for:

_states/umask.py:

```py
import os

def wrap(wrapped_state, mask, *args, **kwargs):
    old_umask = None
    try:
        if not __opts__["test"]:
            old_umask = os.umask(int(mask, base=8))
        return __states__[wrapped_state](*args, **kwargs)
    finally:
        if old_umask is not None:
            os.umask(old_umask)
```

Usage:

```
"install python requests package":
  umask.wrap:
    - wrapped_state: pip.installed
    - mask: '022'
    - name: requests
```

Answer (score 1):

**This answer is for versions <3006**

No, there's no facility for changing the umask of the running Salt process.

What you could do is start a new process with `cmd.run`:

```yaml
install python module:
  cmd.run:
    - name: pip install foo
    - umask: '077'
    - unless:
      - fun: pip.is_installed
        pkgname: foo

install python module at version:
  cmd.run:
    - name: pip install bar==4.2
    - umask: '077'
    - unless:
      - pip freeze | grep bar==4.2
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify a specific version and/or a `>=` version to the `pip.is_installed` function?

Comment: @bdrx no, but see edit